# Sorting a "linked" list in java

Tags: java, sorting

I have following entity in java:

```
public class TodoEntity {
   private int id;
  private int previousId;
}

//Array to sort
List<TodoEntity> unsorted=new ArrayList<>();
```

What is the fastest way to sort this array so that every previousId matches to the id (respectively an item before/after)

---

Current implementation

```
 public static List<TodoEntity> sortEntites(LinkedList<TodoEntity> todoEntities) {
    boolean isClean=true;
    while(isClean){
        boolean isRoundUnclean=false;
        for(int i=0;i<todoEntities.size();i++){
            TodoEntity todoEntity=todoEntities.get(i);
            if(i>0){
                TodoEntity todoEntityPrevious=todoEntities.get(i-1);
                if(todoEntity.getPrevious()!= null && !todoEntity.getPrevious().equals(todoEntityPrevious.getGuid())){
                    int index=getIndex(todoEntities,todoEntity.getPrevious());
                    todoEntities.remove(i);
                    todoEntities.add(index,todoEntity);
                    isRoundUnclean=true;
                    break;
                }
                if(todoEntity.getPrevious()==null){
                    todoEntities.remove(i);
                    todoEntities.add(0,todoEntity);
                }
            }
        }
        isClean = isRoundUnclean;
    }
    return todoEntities;
}
```

Comment: What about the first one?

Comment: what do you mean by `that every previousId matches to the id`?

Comment: Meaning -> `todoEntity.get(i).previousId === todoEntity.get(i-1).id`

Comment: If you want them in order and insertion is a frequent operation, I would not recommend `ArrayList`, since it's insertion is costly. I'd simply create a 'real' `LinkedList` from your collection of `TodoEntity`, by iterating over it and adding it in a correct place

Comment: Sounds like a topological sort

Answer (score 0):

This list is not linked. A linked list is a list which stores references and data instead of array data. To create a linked list just change

> `List<TodoEntity> unsorted=new ArrayList<>();`

to

```
List<TodoEntity> unsorted = new LinkedList<>();
```

However, to answer your question, just call `Collections.sort(unsorted);` to sort your list and add a comparable to your TodoEntity class.

Example (sorts ids in ascending order with matching ids matching):

```
public class TodoEntity implements Comparable<TodoEntity>{
    private int id;
    private int previousId;
    @Override
    public int compareTo(TodoEntity other){
        if(this.id == other.previousID)
            return -1;
        if(this.previousID == other.id)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't understand the question.

Comment: This violates about every requirement of the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) interface.